# Android code lags due to logging / gc / audioManager

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, android-logcat, android-audiomanager

To keep it simple: I'm working on a small app where we want to click several objects after each other. On clicking an object, it is supposed to play a sound.

This works well, except that from time to time, the entire app (including LogCat's logging) just freezes for about 5 seconds, after which it seems to catch up. (All threads freeze)
With catching up I mean; if you continue clicking during the freeze, after unfreezing, it still knows what to do.

The Log is simple:

> 01-17 14:52:08.292: D/AudioManager(17963): setStreamVolume(streamType:3, index:11, flags:0)
> 01-17 14:52:08.473: D/dalvikvm(17963): GC_CONCURRENT freed 417K, 48% free 3113K/5895K, external 140K/647K, paused 2ms+4ms
>
> 01-17 14:52:09.033: D/AudioManager(17963): setStreamVolume(streamType:3, index:11, flags:0)
> 01-17 14:52:09.484: D/AudioManager(17963): setStreamVolume(streamType:3, index:11, flags:0)
> 01-17 14:52:10.174: D/AudioManager(17963): setStreamVolume(streamType:3, index:11, flags:0)
> 01-17 14:52:10.785: D/AudioManager(17963): setStreamVolume(streamType:3, index:11, flags:0)
> 01-17 14:52:15.169: D/dalvikvm(17963): GC_EXPLICIT freed 338K, 49% free 3061K/5895K, external 140K/647K, paused 43ms

Notice the 5 second delay between the last two logs.

I tried removing all audio, but that doesn't solve anything.
A text file being logged also does not influence anything apparently.

Does anyone have a clue as how to solve this annoying problem?
Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:**
When pausing the program during the freeze it points to a certain method. What could cause this freeze in this:

```
public synchronized boolean removeEntity(long id)
{
    for (Entity ent : this.entities)
        if (ent.getId() == id)
            return this.entities.remove(ent);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: no code - so not much help as there are different ways of doing what you say. I would use a soundpool if the audio is short and there are a limited number of sounds. The soundpool loads all the audio into memory offering faster access to the audio HOWEVER there are limitations and without code I cannot say what will help.

Comment: Since I have no idea where the problem comes from, posting code is quite impossible. But as mentioned in the post: removing all audio functionality does not solve anything. So the audio has nothing to do with it. (Same for logging it seems... I'll edit the original post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, Nevermind =(

After a days worth of debugging, it turns out I created a ye old dead lock with the synchronized methods. Just weird how it always continues when not hooked to the PC.

My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

That garbage collector is doing a lot of work. Have you tried running Allocation Tracker in DDMS to find out where all this memory is being allocated? If this is a game, make sure you're not creating large objects in the main loop.

Comment: Though it was useful to check the allocations, it did not point me to anything out of the ordinary. Thanks anyway.